# Choose a Sp voice character

Tags: c#, voice, speech, synthesizer

I am using SpeechLib namespace to synthesis two voices. I downloaded two speaker voices, one in Spanish(Hilda) and one in Chinese (han-han. The problem is I don't know how to choice which speaker gonna talk.
For example,

```
private SpVoice spanishSpeaker = new SpVoice();
private SpVoice chineseSpeaker = new SpVoice();
```

The program always initialize the variables using the first downloaded voice.
I wanna know how I can change,choose, select which voice gonna use for any synthesizer voice.

Reference:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723614(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I saw it but I dont understand how to do that because I am a beginner programmer.. I tried several combinations but I am here praying for help because I didnt found how to